# Change membership level based on points in Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, membership

I'm looking for a plugin that can create points based on product's price and when user have collected certain amount of points they will be automatically upgraded to a new level of membership. This new membership allows them to receive a different range of price. Kindly reply or comment if there's any suggestions and thanks in advance !

Comment: try this for the system of points : https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-points-and-rewards/ after that, you certainly need a developer to change the cost depending of the number of points

Comment: Please, remember that **asking for a plugin or tutorial recommendation is just off topic** on StackOverFlow. Now WooCommerce Points and Rewards and similar plugins **will not be convenient in your case…** So you should need to develop yourself this or to ask someone to do it for you.